# Find which dependency jar has required class

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

How can you find which dependency to import if you just know the class name.

Imagine i am getting error

hbase/mapreduce/HbaseDBMapper.java:[9,53] package org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.replication does not exist

This is due to fact that i dont have dependency which can give me this package.

How can i find which dependency to import from maven repository or any other website

Answer (score 0):

In general, http://www.findjar.com/ can be used to find the jar files and consequent maven dependencies, given a class.

In this specific case, you may want

```
<artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
<groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
```

as the class is defined in https://github.com/apache/hbase/tree/master/hbase-server/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce